# Как здесь сделать так, чтобы не было вертикальной полосы прокрутки?

Tags: css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="bigtext.js"></script>
  <style>
    html {
      height: 100%;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: #58cdcd;
      border-width: 1px;
    }
    
    body {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: #cd5858;
      border-width: 1px;
    }
    
    .footer {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      left: 0;
      text-align: center;
      /*background-color: rgba(180, 215, 255, 0.096);*/
      height: 30px;
      vertical-align: middle;
      color: #383535;
      font-family: 'Great Vibes', cursive;
      /*color: rgb(233, 181, 38);*/
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: #cacd58;
      border-width: 1px;
    }
    
    .footer a {
      font-family: 'Great Vibes', cursive;
      vertical-align: middle;
      color: #383535;
      /*color: rgb(233, 181, 38);*/
    }
    
    .footer a:hover {
      /* color: rgba(6, 31, 100, 0.425);*/
      color: rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.781);
      /*color: rgba(233, 181, 38, 0.671);*/
    }
    
    #page {
      margin: 36px auto;
      width: 90%;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: #cacd58;
      border-width: 1px;
      padding-bottom: 100px;
    }
    
    .blog {
      margin: 0 auto 53px;
      width: 93, 75%;
      /* 900px / 960px */
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: #58bbcd;
      border-width: 1px;
    }
    
    .blog .main {
      float: left;
      width: 62.8888889%;
      /* 566px / 900px */
    }
    
    .blog .other {
      float: right;
      width: 36.7777778%;
      /* 331px / 900px */
    }
    
    .lede {
      padding: 0.8em 5.33333333%;
      /* 48px / 900px */
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: #080806;
      border-width: 1px;
    }
    
    .recent-entries {
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 69.7885196%;
      /* 231px / 331px */
    }
    
    .article {
      padding: 0 8.48056537%;
      /* 48px / 566px */
    }
    
    .date {
      float: left;
      margin: 24px 0 0 -17.0886076%;
      /* 81px / 474px */
      width: 14.556962%;
      /* 69px / 474px */
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: #e7e725;
      border-width: 1px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="page">
    <div class="blog section">
      <h1 class="lede">Recently in <a href="#">The Bot Blog</a></h1>
      <div class="main">
        <div class="article">
          <div class="date">
            <h1>34</h1>
          </div>
          <a>fgggggggg
                  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
                  ggggggh fghf</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /end .main -->
      <div class="other">
        <div class="recent-entries">
          <a>fggggggggg
  gggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
  ggggggh fghf</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /end .other -->
    </div>
    <!-- /end .blog.section -->
  </div>
  <!-- /end #page -->
  <div class="footer"><a>fOOTER</a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: html { overflow: hidden}. Но как тогда скролить страницу?

Comment: стандартные стили сбрасывать надо ...

Comment: overflow: hidden, ну никак не скролить, но мне надо чтоб можно было скролить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотреть на полную страницу

В самый низ добавил вот это

```
 html,body{
   margin:0;
   padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="bigtext.js"></script>
  <style>
    html {
      height: 100%;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: #58cdcd;
      border-width: 1px;
    }
    
    body {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: #cd5858;
      border-width: 1px;
    }
    
    .footer {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      left: 0;
      text-align: center;
      /*background-color: rgba(180, 215, 255, 0.096);*/
      height: 30px;
      vertical-align: middle;
      color: #383535;
      font-family: 'Great Vibes', cursive;
      /*color: rgb(233, 181, 38);*/
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: #cacd58;
      border-width: 1px;
    }
    
    .footer a {
      font-family: 'Great Vibes', cursive;
      vertical-align: middle;
      color: #383535;
      /*color: rgb(233, 181, 38);*/
    }
    
    .footer a:hover {
      /* color: rgba(6, 31, 100, 0.425);*/
      color: rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.781);
      /*color: rgba(233, 181, 38, 0.671);*/
    }
    
    #page {
      margin: 36px auto;
      width: 90%;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: #cacd58;
      border-width: 1px;
      padding-bottom: 100px;
    }
    
    .blog {
      margin: 0 auto 53px;
      width: 93, 75%;
      /* 900px / 960px */
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: #58bbcd;
      border-width: 1px;
    }
    
    .blog .main {
      float: left;
      width: 62.8888889%;
      /* 566px / 900px */
    }
    
    .blog .other {
      float: right;
      width: 36.7777778%;
      /* 331px / 900px */
    }
    
    .lede {
      padding: 0.8em 5.33333333%;
      /* 48px / 900px */
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: #080806;
      border-width: 1px;
    }
    
    .recent-entries {
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 69.7885196%;
      /* 231px / 331px */
    }
    
    .article {
      padding: 0 8.48056537%;
      /* 48px /
566px */
    }
    
    .date {
      float: left;
      margin: 24px 0 0 -17.0886076%;
      /* 81px / 474px */
      width: 14.556962%;
      /* 69px / 474px */
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: #e7e725;
      border-width: 1px;
    }
    
    html,
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="page">
    <div class="blog section">

      <h1 class="lede">Recently in <a href="#">The Bot Blog</a></h1>
      <div class="main">

        <div class="article">
          <div class="date">
            <h1>34</h1>

          </div>
          <a>fgggggggg
                  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
                  ggggggh fghf</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /end .main -->

      <div class="other">
        <div class="recent-entries">
          <a>fggggggggg
  gggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
  ggggggh fghf</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /end .other -->
    </div>
    <!-- /end .blog.section -->


  </div>
  <!-- /end #page -->


  <div class="footer"><a>fOOTER</a>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Задать следующие стили для `body`:

```
width: 100vw;
overflow: hidden;
```

Далее обернуть всё в `body` каким-нибудь элементом, у меня это `div#wrapper` и ему задать следующие стили:

```
#wrapper {
  width: calc(100vw + 30px); /* примерная ширина скролл бара */
  padding-right: 30px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Из этого мы получим некий "хак", который визуально уберёт вертикальный скролл, но оставит возможность скроллить страницу.

Вот демо:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #58cdcd;
  border-width: 1px;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #cd5858;
  border-width: 1px;
  /* Добавить следующее */
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Добавить следующее */
#wrapper {
  width: calc(100vw + 30px); /* примерная ширина скролл бара */
  padding-right: 30px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  /*background-color: rgba(180, 215, 255, 0.096);*/
  height: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #383535;
  font-family: 'Great Vibes', cursive;
  /*color: rgb(233, 181, 38);*/
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #cacd58;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.footer a {
  font-family: 'Great Vibes', cursive;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #383535;
  /*color: rgb(233, 181, 38);*/
}

.footer a:hover {
  /* color: rgba(6, 31, 100, 0.425);*/
  color: rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.781);
  /*color: rgba(233, 181, 38, 0.671);*/
}

#page {
  margin: 36px auto;
  width: 90%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #cacd58;
  border-width: 1px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.blog {
  margin: 0 auto 53px;
  width: 93, 75%;
  /* 900px / 960px */
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #58bbcd;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.blog .main {
  float: left;
  width: 62.8888889%;
  /* 566px / 900px */
}

.blog .other {
  float: right;
  width: 36.7777778%;
  /* 331px / 900px */
}

.lede {
  padding: 0.8em 5.33333333%;
  /* 48px / 900px */
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #080806;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.recent-entries {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 69.7885196%;
  /* 231px / 331px */
}

.article {
  padding: 0 8.48056537%;
  /* 48px /
566px */
}

.date {
  float: left;
  margin: 24px 0 0 -17.0886076%;
  /* 81px / 474px */
  width: 14.556962%;
  /* 69px / 474px */
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #e7e725;
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="page">
    <div class="blog section">

      <h1 class="lede">Recently in <a href="#">The Bot Blog</a></h1>
      <div class="main">

        <div class="article">
          <div class="date">
            <h1>34</h1>

          </div>
          <a>fgggggggg
                  ggggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
                  ggggggh fghf</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /end .main -->

      <div class="other">
        <div class="recent-entries">
          <a>fggggggggg
  gggggggh ffffffffhgf hfgggggg
  ggggggh fghf</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /end .other -->
    </div>
    <!-- /end .blog.section -->


  </div>
  <!-- /end #page -->


  <div class="footer"><a>fOOTER</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: ну так то да конечно но пол подвала скрыто

Answer (score -1):

Уберите этот стиль:

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```